# Flutter: I want to assign values of String from each for loop in to a list of Strings in flutter but getting error that invalid range

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

```
List<String> path = <String>[];
loopRun(int i) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      print("Called");
      
      _getData(
          files[i].toString(), i);
    }
  }
_getData(file, int i) async {    
    String thumb = file;
    print(thumb); 
    path[i] = thumb;
    print(path[i]);
    setState(() {      
    });
    return thumb;
  }
```

In the above code, I am calling the loopRun(3) and the loop is running three times and I am seeing the value of thumb in the console which are returning 3 strings. I have to assign each String of thumb in path. For that I declared empty String list path and trying to assign in path[i] but getting the below error.

```
E/flutter (15093): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (15093): #0      List._setIndexed (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:262:73)
E/flutter (15093): #1      List.[]= (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:258:5)
E/flutter (15093): #2      _MyHomePageState._getData
package:dtp22/main.dart:124
E/flutter (15093): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15093):

E/flutter (15093): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1
E/flutter (15093): #0      List._setIndexed (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:262:73)
E/flutter (15093): #1      List.[]= (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:258:5)
E/flutter (15093): #2      _MyHomePageState._getData
package:dtp22/main.dart:124
E/flutter (15093): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15093):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to insert an element at a specific index which I think you are trying to achieve by

```
path[i] = thumb;
```

is not the right way, instead use the insert function, which for your case will look like

```
path.insert(i, thumb);
```

Comment: I am trying to display that path[i] in leading of Listtile in listviewbuilder as path[index]...but for a moment it is showing error The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
But output is displayed after showing that error...How to get rid of that error

Comment: can you please explain more clearly what it is you are trying to do? Perhaps post another question with the code so things will be more clear.

Comment: Due to some wrong condition i got that error i mentioned in comment..solved now..thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<int, String> path = new Map<int, String>();

List<String> files = <String>["test1","test2","test3"];

_getData(file, int i) async {    
    String thumb = file;
    path[i] = thumb;
    print(path[i]);
    return thumb;
  }
loopRun(int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      print("Called");
      
      _getData(
          files[j].toString(), j);
    }
}
```